# 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'save'

Tags: django, post, django-models, django-forms, django-views

This is the models.py code

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')



@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    instance.profile.save()


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # Profile.objects.save()
    instance.profile.save()
```

and This the views.py code:

```
def signup(request):
    ....

    if request.method == "POST":
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            user.save(using='default')
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponse("User Loged In")
```

Then after fill the registration form and click the submit button, Django get me the following Error:
[image: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'save']

Comment: A `user` can in your `model` have several `profile`s.

Comment: Tanx @WillemVanOnsem, I didn't pay enough attention in my implementation, tanx so much...!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You defined a `ForeignKey` from a `Profile` to a `User`, but that means every `Profile` is attached to *a* `User`, it is however perfectly possible that *multiple* `Profile`s are attached to the *same* `User`.

Hence if you use `a_user.profile`, it will *not* return a *single* `Profile`, but a `RelatedManager`: a manager that manages the *collection* (that can contain zero, one or multiple elements) of `Profile`.

I think however that you actually want to associated `Profile`s with *distinct* `User`s, in which case you better use a [**`OneToOneField`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField):

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

If you then query `someuser.profile` you will either get a `Profile` instance, or it will raise a `Profile.DoesNotExists` error in case no profile is associated with that user.

By default the `related_name` of a `OneToOneField` is the name of the class in lowercase, so you no longer need to specify this.

Note however that in your code `instance.profile.save()` is *not* necessary, since the `Profile`, is basically already saved by creating it:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    # unnecessary
    # instance.profile.save()
```